# Scroll view doesn't work in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scroll view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/antiquewhiter"
    android:weightSum="100"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@drawable/green_gradient_top_bar"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/log_in_header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/Einloggen_text"
            style="@style/headerfromdialogs" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/log_in_header_exit_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_in_header_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:onClick="finish"
            android:src="@drawable/x_android" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/Benutzername_text"
            style="@style/dialogsGreenTexts" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name_log_in" 
            >

        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/log_in_passwort_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:text="@string/Passwort_text"
            style="@style/dialogsGreenTexts" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/log_in_passwort_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/log_in_passwort_text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_in_passwort_text"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword" 
            android:hint="@string/hint_passwort_log_in" 
            >

        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log_in_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/log_in_passwort_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:onClick="logIn"
            android:text="@string/Login_text"
            style="@style/bold_text18" />
<!--             android:background="@drawable/green_gradient_button" -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/log_in_passwort_vergessen_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/log_in_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_passwort_edit_text"
            android:text="@string/Passwort_vergessen_text"
            style="@style/dialogsGreenTexts" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/waitProgessBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userError"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/errorRed"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to scroll because on my se xperia neo V in horizontal orientation I can't see all view. Second problem is when I change orientation all view is broke. How change this view to show properly in both orientations?

but scroll doesn't work. Anyone know Why?

Comment: Is your layout more than large as compare to screen ? if yes then and then scroll view come .

Comment: What are the child views you are having inside the layout, ask clearly...

Comment: What do you want scroll ? Provide detailed code so that you can get correct response, depending on what you want to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please note :**

1) Scroll view must have a single child (i.e all views must be included within a single root layout inside scroll view)

2) ScrollView works when your page size is greater the default height of the screen .

Please check both these things and if still does not work ... Paste some code to have a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="500dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/antiquewhiter"
android:weightSum="100"
>

<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@drawable/green_gradient_top_bar"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log_in_header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Einloggen_text"
        style="@style/headerfromdialogs" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/log_in_header_exit_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_in_header_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="finish"
        android:src="@drawable/x_android" />

 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/Benutzername_text"
        style="@style/dialogsGreenTexts" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_name_log_in" 
        >

    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log_in_passwort_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_benutzername_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/Passwort_text"
        style="@style/dialogsGreenTexts" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/log_in_passwort_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/log_in_passwort_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_in_passwort_text"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:hint="@string/hint_passwort_log_in" 
        >

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/log_in_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/log_in_passwort_edit_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:onClick="logIn"
        android:text="@string/Login_text"
        style="@style/bold_text18" />
      <!-- android:background="@drawable/green_gradient_button" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log_in_passwort_vergessen_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/log_in_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_passwort_edit_text"
        android:text="@string/Passwort_vergessen_text"
        style="@style/dialogsGreenTexts" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/waitProgessBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userError"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log_in_benutzername_edit_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/errorRed"/>

</RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```